# How to perform a MERGE (insert/update/delete) using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` to be able to *upsert* some data in a PostgreSQL table.

But now I'd also like to be able to *delete* some existing rows, if they are not provided by the current `INSERT` query. So, in addition to `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, I would like to be able to do a `DELETE`.

Using `SQL Server`, I would do this using a `MERGE` query and :

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
```

What is the recommended way to achieve something similar using `PostgreSQL`?

I would prefere *not* to run two separated queries.

Comment: We can't do that yet :^( Wait for PostgreSQL v12 which will probably have a `MERGE` statement...

Comment: So how do you workaround it using PostgreSQL? I mean, it's not such an edge case... Two requests are mandatory?

Comment: I think you will have to use two statements, yes.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a CTE for that

```
WITH updated AS (
INSERT ... 
INTO tbl 
ON CONFLICT ...
RETURNING your_primary_key
)
DELETE FROM tbl t 
WHERE your_primary_key NOT IN ( 
  SELECT updated.your_primary_key FROM updated
);
```

Comment: could you please create an example of the above? I'm not able to update values which already have an id (serial primary key) and insert values which do not exist in table.